# How to split a street address in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, split

I have a column that contains a street address. Below are some examples of how that street address could be.

Question is: how do I break this into individual columns for `str_number`, `str_prefix` (may or may not exist), `Str_Name` (could be one or more words), `str_type`, `str_suffix` (may or may not exist).

I'm not sure if this is possible in SQL, with some values not being there but thought I would check. Thank you very much for any assistance.

- 123 N Main ST E
- 456 Bear Creek AVE W
- 789 N Rose LN
- 234 E Deer Run Ln

Comment: Hi SDR, I would recommend that you review the [help] and take the [tour], that will show you how to ask a question. You'll need to provide information about what you have tried to do the task yourself, what you expect to see as a result, etc.

Answer (score 4):

You can't do this reliably, as there are far too many variations on how addresses are formatted, abbreviated, etc. See [Falsehoods programmers believe about addresses](https://www.mjt.me.uk/posts/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-addresses/).

You would be much better off writing/finding an application which submits each address to a service (API) which can then look up against a known address database and return the constituent components in a structured format, then insert that "cleansed" data into proper fields in the database.

Comment: One of my first jobs was working on a system like this. You _can_ do it [pretty] reliably, but it requires a **lot** of heuristics, along with an understanding of regional variations in how street addresses look. For instance, a street address in the Southwest might be recorded in Spanish/Mexican style: `C. Francisco I. Madero No. 115`, with the house number aft. And even using "standard" US street address format, You might have `123 E Main St` or `123 Main St E` (and each might coexist in the same town).

Best to not even try. Or use a commercial service.